# “error: no such device” at boot in Ubuntu Server 11.10 with Raid1

Tags: ubuntu, webserver, software-raid, raid1

I have a configuration of 4 HDD's as Raid1 2 pairs of 2 HDD's. First Raid1 pair is for system, so I just made an 40GB space for swap, and the rest of it for the root, the second pair of Raid1 is for logical use. So, in final I have:

**First pair:**

1. Disk:

   - 40GB swap
   - 960GB / ext4 raid
2. Disk:

   - 40GB swap
   - 960GB / ext4 raid

   **Second pair:**
3. Disk:

   - 1.0 TB ext4 raid
4. Disk:

   - 1.0 TB ext4 raid

After the system installed, at boot up I see a strange error for about 5-6 seconds:

```
error: no such device: c3b8763c-4623-4fe1-9096-3aadef5cc116
Press any key to continue...
```

So the question is, what I did wrong?

The output of `ls -l /dev/disk/by-uuid` is:

```
total 0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 9 2012-04-24 15:38 c3b8763c-4623-4fe1-9096-    3aadef5cc116 -> ../../md0
```

The output of fstab:

[image: fstab]

The output of mdadm:

[image: mdadm]

Comment: When you execute 'ls -l /dev/disk/by-uuid/' do you see a disk with UUID c3b8763c-4623-4fe1-9096-3aadef5cc116? If you go in /etc/fstab, do you see it and if yes for which mount point?

Comment: Ok, I've edited first post with an output of ls -l and fstab :) Thanks

Comment: Perhaps you should ty to see the status of your raid array: 'sudo mdadm -D /dev/md0' In addition during the installation did you follow the instruction given by Ubuntu: https://help.ubuntu.com/11.10/serverguide/C/advanced-installation.html the 1st chapter is about Software RAID installation. Check the bootable flag hint.

Comment: I checked the flag, I know about it. So the output of mdadm is in first post. Thanks :)

Comment: You might want to check `cat /proc/mdstat`. Both RAID sets should show up, including rebuilding progress.

Comment: Both is rebuilded already, both raids is active, that is what is shown with cat /proc/mdstat

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**RAID is resyncing HDD**

There are 2 hints:

1. "State : active, resyncing"
2. "Rebuild status : 17% complete"

It seems that your system is rebuilding your array (or it did not finished syncing it during installation).

It should be bootable again once the array is finished rebuilding.

For the time being, you could ty to boot in degraded mode at least. You can use 'bootdegraded=true' in grub (press e to edit the boot line and add the option).

*Note: I had this as a comment, but I think this is the answer to your question, so I moved it.*

Comment: Ok thanks, but I checked degraded mode as Yes at installation time. Ok, I'll try again and will see whats the deal :) thanks

Comment: That's maybe why you can still boot then :) Keep monitoring the Rebuild status. I think /proc/mdadm gives more info on the rebuilding. And once done, it should be all fine (hopefully)

Comment: Ok, I've waited the rebuild and that didn't gave me the success result. So I've decided to reinstall it, and it is ok now, thanks for the help.